# Where did I go wrong with my answer?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, balls-in-bins

Question: 10 unique balls are distributed randomly among 8 ordered baskets, what is the probability that the first basket is empty and the second basket has at least 1 ball in it?

My approach:
first we put one ball inside the second basket, there are $10$ ways to do this, for each ball we put in the second basket we have $7^9$ ways to distribute the remaining 9 balls into 7 baskets. Now since it's obvious that our sample space is of size $8^{10}$ we get that the answer is
$\frac{10*7^9}{8^{10}}$

however that answer makes no sense since $10*7^9 > 7^{10}$ which is the number of ways to distribute 10 balls into 7 baskets(without the limitation that the second basket must have atleast 1 ball). Can someone explain to me where I went wrong?

Also please note that I'm not interested in getting the right answer using a different approach I'm specifically trying to understand what is wrong with my reasoning

Comment: By designating a particular ball as the ball placed in the second basket, you count each distribution in which more than one ball is placed in that basket multiple times.

Comment: You are way double counting.  You are counting putting the green ball in the second basket before putting the red ball into the second basket as different than putting the red ball in first and then the green ball.

Comment: I suppose if you want to do it that way you must calculate the sum is $10\times 6^9 + {10\choose 2}\times 6^8 + ..... = \sum_{k=1}^{10} {10\choose k}6^{9-k}$.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Where did I go wrong with my answer?" says nothing about the subject of the question. It's a useless title.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_i$, for each $i=1,2,\ldots, 10$, be the event

$$A_i = \{\text{Ball $i$ is in the second basket,}$$ $$\text{and the first basket is empty}\}.$$ Then indeed, ${\bf{P}}[A_i]$ is, $\frac{7^9}{8^{10}}$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots, 10$. You however, want to calculate ${\bf{P}}[A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \ldots A_{10}]$, and to this end you [incorrectly] claimed that ${\bf{P}}[A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \ldots A_{10}]$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{10}{\bf{P}}[A_i]$ $=$ $\frac{10 \times 7^9}{8^{10}}$. This would be correct **iff the $A_i$s were disjoint.**

Where this is  wrong however, is that the $A_i$s are ***not*** disjoint, and so ${\bf{P}}[A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \ldots A_{10}]$ is strictly less than $\sum_{i=1}^{10}{\bf{P}}[A_i]$ $=$ $\frac{10 \times 7^9}{8^{10}}$, and not equal, as you have claimed.

Answer (score 0):

You over-counted.

Label the balls as B-1, B-2, ..., B-10.

Label the baskets K-1, K-2, ..., K-8.

Consider the **very specific case** where B-1 and B-2 both go into K-2, and the other $8$ balls all go into K-3.

Any algorithm that you adopt that enumerates each of the satisfying ways (i.e. K-1 empty, K-2 not empty) of distributing the $10$ balls, must **count** the specific case detailed in the previous paragraph, **exactly once.**

However, your computation of

$$10 \times 7^9 \tag1 $$

counts the specific situation **more than once**.

In (1) above, the first factor represents that there are $(10)$ choices for the ball that goes into K-2.

So, the specific case will be counted once when B-1 is the **first** ball sent to K-2 and then the specific case will be counted a **second time**, when B-2 is the **first ball** sent to K-2.

**This is no good**.

---

Although you did not specifically request a remedy, I will provide what I regard as the standard remedy.

The number of ways that basket K-1 can be left empty is $7^{(10)}.$

The number of ways that baskets K-1 and K-2 can both be left empty is $6^{(10)}.$

Therefore, the number of ways that basket K-1 can be left empty, without leaving basket K-2 empty is

$$7^{(10)} - 6^{(10)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional probability: Let $N_i=$the number of balls in basket $i$.  Let $B$ be the event that $N_1=0$.  Let $A$ be the event that $N_2\ge 1$.  We're looking for $P(AB)$.  We know $P(B)=(7/8)^{10}$.  We don't know $A$, but can condition on $B$: $P(AB)=P(A|B)P(B)$.  I.e., $P(A|B)=1-P(N_2=0|N_1=0)=1-(6/7)^{10}$.  Putting it together to get $(7^{10}-6^{10})/ 8^{10}$.